# Prove a homomorphism between $\mathbb R$ and $(-1,1)$

Tags: general-topology

I found a homomorphism in a book, between $\mathbb R$ and $(-1,1)$ this is:

$f(x)=\frac{x}{1+|x|}$

So i check the bijection.Firts, I have to check if $f(x_{1})=f(x_{2})$ then $x_{1}=x_{2}$ but i have this:

$\frac{x_{1}}{1+|x_{1}|}=\frac{x_{2}}{1+|x_{2}|}$

I don't know how can i proceed with the absolute value and how can i see the continuity? Can you give some hint? Thank you.

Comment: Could those two things be equal if x1 was positive and x2 was negative?

Comment: No, but it's correct if i consider the cases when they have the same signs and when they don't have ?

Comment: You mean homeomorphism, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are defining $f:\mathbb R \to (-1,1)$ (and not $f:(-1,1) \to\mathbb R $).
Take absolute value on both sides to get $\frac {|x_1|}{1+|x_1|}=\frac {|x_2|}{1+|x_2|}$ Cross multiply and conclude that $|x_1|+|x_1||x_2|=|x_2|+|x_1||x_2|$ so $|x_1|=|x_2|$. Now go back to the original equation.

Continuity follows from the fact that ratio of two continuous functions with denominator not vanishing is continuous. Continuity of the inverse function is proved by actually calculating the inverse: Show that $f^{-1}(y)=\frac y {1-|y|}$.

Comment: Why you take the absolute value on both sides?

Comment: Because that helps me to show that $x_1=x_2$. Alternatively you can consider the four cases based on the signs of $x_1$ and $x_2$. @angieduque

Comment: Yes, this solution is more elegant and short. When i see the continuity, can i try too with the criterion of open sets and continuity? And the inverse function is continuos if i prove is 1-1 and because i know $f$ is continuos.